# CSWP Picture URL

Tags: cswp

I have a site with a CSWP which lists certain sites.
I would like to have a logo next to each site name.

I have tried passing my url into the picture url field but the logo doesn't show up

[image: CSWP picture url]

Can I pass a straight url for my logo image or I do have to go through managed properties and incremental search (which it's very slow in my case)?

Comment: did you find the answer to this?

Comment: No I didn't. I did something with the code eventually